Diagonalizability results via the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over ED
I'm looking for a better understanding of results about when a linear transformation is diagonalizable by using the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a Euclidean domain.
Result 1: One such result is that if we suppose:

$V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$
$T : V \to V$ is linear
$T$ is normal

Then this implies that

$T$ is diagonalisable

One proof uses induction on $\dim V$, noting that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ then
$$
V = \langle v \rangle \oplus \langle v\rangle^\perp
$$
and then since $T$ is normal, this gives us enough information to deduce that both $\langle v \rangle$ and $\langle v \rangle^\perp$ are $T$-invariant and so by gluing together $\left\{\frac{v}{||v||}\right\}$ and an orthonormal basis for $\langle v \rangle^\perp$ (which exists by the inductive hypothesis), we can diagonalise $T$.
Instead I want to consider if we give $\mathbb C^n$ the structure of a $\mathbb C[x]$- module via the action $x \cdot v \mapsto Tv$, the structure theorem implies
$$
V \cong \bigoplus^k_{i = 1} \frac{\mathbb C[x]}{\langle d_i(x) \rangle}
$$
for some invariant factors $d_1(x), \ldots, d_k(x)$ of the presentation matrix $xI - T$. How we can use the assumption that $T$ is normal in order to deduce that in fact
$$
V \cong \bigoplus^n_{i = 1} \frac{\mathbb C[x]}{\langle x - \lambda_i\rangle}
$$
for eigenvectors $\lambda_i$?
Result 2: Another result is that if:

$V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$
$T : V \to V$ linear
$T$ is orthogonal

Then there exists an orthonormal basis $\mathcal B$ such that
$$
T \sim 
\begin{bmatrix}
I & & & \\
& -I & & \\
& & R_{\theta_1} & & \\
& & &  \ddots & \\
& & & & R_{\theta_\ell} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where each
$$
R_{\theta_i} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta_i & -\sin\theta_i \\\\ \sin \theta_i & \cos \theta_i \end{bmatrix} \quad \theta_i \neq 0, \pi.
$$
The proof I have for this (here, Theorem 8.32) relies on quite a messy argument based on defining $S := T + T^{-1}$ and then using the fact this is self-adjoint. I feel like there is an easier proof (assuming the structure theorem) by somehow showing something along the lines of
$$
V \cong \bigoplus^k_{i = 1} \frac{\mathbb R[x]}{\langle x - \lambda_i\rangle} \oplus \bigoplus^\ell_{j = 1} \frac{\mathbb R[x]}{\langle x^2 - (\mu_j + \overline\mu_j) x + \mu_j \overline\mu_j \rangle}
$$
where $\lambda_i = \pm 1$ and $\mu_j, \overline \mu_j$ are the eigenvectors of $T$, but again can't think how to relate the fact $T$ is orthogonal to the invariant factors in the decomposition given by the structure theorem. Is there a simple proof that uses this idea?
